# Mysql Query: create Customer/agent relationship in which each customer will have order/position/priority to handle

Tags: php, mysql

I have to create Customer/agent relationship, in which each agent may handle 100 customers, and each customer will have **order/position/priority** to handle. And when i update a customer's  **order/position/priority** to some other priority.

For example from 5 to 25 then the position already occupied customer needs to go one step down 24 so then the 24 th to 23 it will goes upto the 6 th customer goes to 5th.

So is there anyway to have custom sql query or php script (For loop can do that, but i want something else if it is possible)) to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourTable SET priority = priority + 1 WHERE priority >= 24
UPDATE yourTable SET priority = 24 WHERE priority = 5
UPDATE yourTable SET priority = priority - 1 WHERE priority > 5
```

Preferablu it should be done within a transaction.

Comment: Excellent and quick answer. Thanks for your answer Mchl.

Comment: Also this can be do that.
 update customer_agent set position = position -1 where position <= $targetValue and position > $currentValue
 update customer_agent set position = $targetValue where position = $currentValue . Is anybody know how to combine these two queries into one update query

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

UPDATE customer SET position=position-1 WHERE position>$position_open

Comment: Oh, this would work if you're taking a customer out of the queue and $position_open is the position that customer used to occupy. If you're moving the customer to a different position in the queue, then Mchl's solution looks better.